The custom queries that were set up are not being displayed
The custom queries that were set up are not being displayed.
When I open a configured data source, I used to see the custom queries that had been set up, but now they are no longer visible. Your prompt assistance with this matter would be greatly appreciated.
I wrote a ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/358393591
